# Having trouble calling a method from a button inside a cell in UITableView in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton

I have a UITableViewController that has a tableView.  Each cell has a button that can be selected/deslected like a checkbox, and the method that does this is working fine.  I would like to have another method that gets called by a button in the tableheaderview that is able to iterate through this list and select all of the buttons in one fell swoop. The irony is that I am able to perform the iteration, but can't seem to call the method that selects/deselects the button.

Here is my relevant code:

```
//This is my method does the iteration
- (void) startWizard {

    NSLog(@"Did it select?");

    for (int i = 0; i < [self.tableView numberOfSections]; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:i]; j++) {
            NSUInteger ints[2] = {i,j};
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndexes:ints length:2];
            UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            //Here is my code to call the method that selects/deselects
            [self buttonTouched:nil];



        }
    }
}
```

and here is the method that does the actual select/deselect of each individual button (and works fine):

```
-(void)buttonTouched:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;

    if( [[btn imageForState:UIControlStateNormal] isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CheckBox1.png"]])
    {
        [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CheckBox2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        // other statements
    }
    else
    {
        [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CheckBox1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        // other statements
    }

}
```

The button in each cell has been added to that cell as its accesseryView as follows:

```
[cell setAccessoryView:testButton];
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong, and how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call in the loop `[self buttonTouched:nil];` you call the method `buttonTouched` with `nil` as value for `sender`. Therefore, the first line in `buttonTouched` sets `btn` to `nil` and the rest of the methods operates on the nil button.
Either find a way to pass the actual button object to `buttonTouched` or pass the indexPath an d find the correct button by that.

Comment: Thanks so much for your prompt reply.  I have the following line in my code:  NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndexes:ints length:2];  which retrieves the indexPath.  How would I pass this value to the method that I am trying to call?

Comment: Try `[self buttonTouched:[cell accessoryView]];` in your loop instead of `[self buttonTouched:nil];`